# nodejs: how to deploy a custom SDK along with the nodejs app on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, sdk

I developed a SDK.js that ease the use of my API supported by my nodejs server on Azure.

What would be the best way to deploy this SDK.js to the server so that client can make use of it after having it embedded in their code via a  tag?

Note: I'd like my SDK.js to be babelled and minified in the process.

Answer (score 0):

As far as where to put the file, there are two options I can recommend: either in a public endpoint or by leveraging Azure Storage.

As for deployment, one solution is to include it in whatever deployment process the API. If you are looking for an outside solution, there are a large number out there, but two that will make the process as simple as possible that I am aware of are Azure Devops and Github Actions. Of those two, Github Actions has a larger free tier if your project is small.